# Is there a way to use TypeScript's type system declare a 'template' type as a specific kind of string

Tags: typescript, types

imagine something like this:

```
type SpecificString = StringThatIsSixCharsLongAndAlphaNumeric;
const myFirstSpecificString: SpecificString = '7kj4lj'; // all good
const mySecondSpecificString: SpecificString = '_kj4lj'; // BUILD ERROR
const myThirdSpecificString: SpecificString = 'kj4lj'; // ANOTHER BUILD ERROR
```

how might this be achieved (if at all)? pls. ty

Comment: It is not possible to do. Permutation of all allowed chars exceeds the allowed limit. See tsplay.dev/wQKMnm . See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68724603/how-to-create-a-uuid-template-literal-type-in-typescript/68724963#68724963

Answer (score 0):

As Captain Yossarian said TypeScript does not do this, but one can implement a workaround by using a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates). In the given case of `SpecificString` above say:

```
type SpecificString = string;
const isSpecificString = (value: any): value is SpecificString => {
    return value.length === 6 && value.match(/^[0-9A-Za-z]+$/) !== null
};
const isFirst = isSpecificString('7kj4lj'); // true
const isSecond = isSpecificString('_kj4lj'); // false
const isThird = isSpecificString('kj4lj'); // false
```

The caveat of course is that this happens at runtime rather than compile time but `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`